# Use `needs` keyword in GitLab CI with variable stage name

Tags: gitlab-ci

My pipeline has two different contexts, per se. If a developer is running on a branch other than `main`, a job called `scan_sandbox` is created on the pipeline of the merge request to scan the Dockerfile that the developer is working on currently.

When the branch is merged into `main`, a `scan_production` job is created, implying that the image is going to be pushed to the registry and later used in production environment.

My problem is to deal with this variable stage name, either `scan_sandbox` or `scan_production` with the `needs` statement, in order to fetch and publish the scan results. I've tried...

```
needs: ["scan_production", "scan_sandbox"]
```

But it returns an error, since both stages aren't going to be declared in different contexts. Also tried...

```
needs: ["container_scan"]
```

Which is the name of the `stage` where both scans will run, but GitLab CI also doesn't interpret it this way.

Anyone has any ideas?

Here is an image of the problem:
[image: Pipeline Flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a dependency to be `optional` in Gitlab yaml. In case if it's optional, Gitlab won't fail if the stage was not executed.  It is specifically added to handle the stages with  `rules`, `only`, or `except` conditions.

So you can specify

```
needs:
    - job: scan_sandbox
      optional: true
    - job: scan_production
      optional: true
```

Notes:

- This will work for Gitlab version >= 13.9
- Doc link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsoptional

Comment: Hey Jay thanks for your reply! I tried that and it worked, the pipeline worked seemlessly. Although my problem is that the process is running when the previous step needing a manual action. Therefore, the job that generates the report to be consumed didn't run yet but the job that processes the report, having the `optional: true` enabled, ran anyways. Do you see a solution to that?